# Reliability of Google Calendar Push Notifications

Tags: api, push-notification, google-calendar-api

I have encountered a problem, that Google notifications quite often do not arrive without any apparent reason. This makes them almost unusable for me, since it seems like they appear just in 60% of cases.

Is this common? Should I stop relying on them and set up a one minute scheduler for syncing event insted?

Thanks for your opinion

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, notification is not 100% reliable also stated in the [document](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push#stopping-notifications). As an alternative you could use [Incremental sync](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/sync#incremental_sync):

> Incremental sync allows you to retrieve all the resources that have been modified since the last sync request. To do this, you need to perform a list request with your most recent sync token specified in the `syncToken` field. Keep in mind that the result will always contain deleted entries, so that the clients get the chance to remove them from storage.

Hope this helps.